# Is it safe to call jQuery methods before DOMReady?

Tags: javascript, jquery, domready

We have a project where jQuery is concatenated into our main javascript application JS file, and I was wondering if it is safe to call jQuery methods before DOMReady?

I see many websites suggest triggering your jQuery javascript **after** DOMReady, for example:

```
$(function(){
  $.each(myObject, function(index, val) {
    ...
  });
});
```

However, this seems to delay the script execution, sometimes causing issues with other application functionality. Since jQuery is already included in the same JS file (at the top), would it not be safe to trigger jQuery methods without waiting for DOMReady?

```
$.each(myObject, function(index, val) {
  ...
});
```

In my tests, it works fine, but I just want to make sure I'm not left to browser randomness. I'm assuming it's fine to run jQuery methods as long as it goes below jQuery definition, and as long as it's not DOM-related activities. Thanks for any input.

Comment: unless you are doing any DOM manipulation you are safe to execute any script code not just jQuery code. Also if the script file you mentioned is at the bottom of page then anyways DOM would be ready by the time your javascript file is loaded.

Comment: If you interact with any elements that appear after the script, then it won't function correctly. If the elements you're interacting with occur before the script then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any jQuery calls before DOMReady. One thing to keep in mind is that if you refer to DOM elements, the executed code will be applied only to the elements already existed in DOM.

For example:

```
<div class="item">

</div>
<script>
    console.log(jQuery('.item').length); // It will output 1
</script>
<div class="item">

</div>
<script>
    console.log(jQuery('.item').length); // It will output 2
</script>
```

Using the DOMReady event to make your initializations is simply a practice to ensure that all elements exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll only run into issues using jQuery methods if jQuery has not yet loaded on the page. If you can guarantee that your script will run after jQuery has loaded, there should not be any issues.

You can do this by putting the jQuery `<script>` tag before your JS `<script>` tag. Or if you bundle your JS together, simply ensure jQuery is bundled in first.

It should be noted, that while you can use jQuery methods as soon as jQuery has loaded, certain elements (for selectors) may not yet be available, depending on where you placed the JS `<script>` tag (or to be more accurate, when your code runs)... so if your code relies on the DOM, waiting for the DOM to "be ready" may not be a bad idea.

**Sidenote:**
If you're just needing to `$.each` an object, you don't have to rely on jQuery, either of the following options would work without any lib dependencies:

**For Old Browser Support (IE8-)**

```
for(var prop in myObject) {
  if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log('The value of '+ prop +' in myObject is '+ myObject[prop]);
  } 
}
```

**For Newer Browsers (IE9+)**

```
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(prop) {
  console.log('The value of '+ prop +' in myObject is '+ myObject[prop]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the element you will call with your jquery is already exist at this step, you are safe to write you code there.

For example you can write your jquery selectors and event binding just after writing the element as html.

We use the ready function just to make sure that everything is already loaded and the full page html is there, because in some cases based on your logic, you are not sure if html element existed or not yet, or may be your event will affect some other elements.